# Sequelize where-clause operator not producing expected output

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am building a password reset feature for an app constructed in NodeJS using Sequelize.

When the user types in their new password and submits, I am querying the database to find the user using the following code:

```
const user = await User.findAll({ where:
        {
            resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
            resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() }
        }
    });
```

However, the query produced by this entry is the following (copied from the terminal, i have added "..." for elements that aren't relevant):

```
Executing (default): SELECT ... `resetPasswordToken`, `resetPasswordExpires` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`resetPasswordToken` = ... AND `user`.`resetPasswordExpires` = '2020-08-09 04:00:00';
```

The current datetime when this query was run was: '2020-08-09 14:24:40', which makes me confused why this sequelized query was translated into "= '2020-08-09 04:00:00'".

The result is that the query doesn't match any user, even though it should have matched one.

My question is the following:

1. Is the syntax of my query correct? It should be searching for datetimes greater than now.
2. If it is correct, is there something else I am missing that would prevent the query from working?

Thanks for your help!

-Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Operator Aliases ($gt) are no longer supported in newer versions of sequelize. use [Op.gt] instead of $gt

try:

```
const user = await User.findAll({ where:
        {
            resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
            resetPasswordExpires: { [Op.gt]: Date.now() }
        }
    });
```

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators

Comment: Yup, I actually found this in the documentation as well. Apologies I didn't see it sooner, and thanks for your help!